# Save DataFrames into json files and name the respective files as the string value of a column

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, to-json

I have a list (called `temp`) of DataFrames where I want to save each DataFrame in a unique JSON File and give the file the name as the string value in the DataFrame column 'symbol'.

My approach is:

```
temp[i].to_json(temp[i][[temp[i]['symbol']] + '.txt') for i in 
temp.symbol.unique()
```

But I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: if `temp` is a list of `DataFrames`, then it has no attribute `symbol`. You'll need to give more information about exactly what temp is, and what the properties of the `DataFrames` in it are. Do they all have one unique symbol, for instance, or can each one have a collection of symbols?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by the string value in the column 'symbol'? The first row's value? If so, the solution is:

```
for df in temp: df.to_json(df.symbol.values[0] + '.txt')
```